# Multisite Setup - Menu Items To Reference Pages in Different Subdomains

Tags: menus, multisite, add-menu-page

I have a multisite setup that has two subdomains. The first is `site1.example.com` which contains pages `page1` and `page2`, and the second subdomain is `site2.example.com` with pages `page3` and `page4`.

I am creating a custom theme for `site1.example.com` in which I would like to **programmatically** create a menu item in `site1.example.com` that references `page3` in `site2.example.com`.

What I have done so far, to programmatically create menu items that reference pages in the same subdomain, is use the function [`wp_update_nav_menu_item()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_nav_menu_item/), as follows:

```
$page = get_post(111); // page id of a page1, that is in the same subdomain

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' => 'Page 1',
    'menu-item-object-id' => $page->ID,
    'menu-item-object' => 'page',
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
    'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
));
```

But to reference a page in another subdomain, I had to set `menu-item-type` to **custom** and use the call as follows

```
wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' => 'Page 3',
    'menu-item-url' => 'http://site2.example.com/page3',
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
    'menu-item-type' => 'custom',
));
```

Now, my question: Is there a way to create a menu item in `site1.example.com` that references `page3` in `site2.example.com` but using the first method above? (please do not ask me why not just use the second solution above, with type **custom**, but the reasons are too long to explain here, and I need use the first method).

I tried the following in the theme for `site1.example.com`:

```
$page = get_post(333); // page id of a page3 in the the second subdomain, which is site2.example.com, which is different than the current subdomain

wp_update_nav_menu_item($menu_id, 0, array(
    'menu-item-title' => 'Page 3',
    'menu-item-object-id' => $page->ID,
    'menu-item-object' => 'page',
    'menu-item-status' => 'publish',
    'menu-item-type' => 'post_type',
));
```

But doing so, resulted in this error in the `debug.log` file

```
[28-Feb-2020 20:31:48 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_parent' of non-object in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 485
[28-Feb-2020 20:31:48 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property 'post_title' of non-object in /var/www/wordpress/wp-includes/nav-menu.php on line 486
```

Obviously WordPress does not like it. But is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WP nav menus can only contain post IDs from the current site.

The reason is, each subsite has its own separate `wp_posts` table. When you add items by ID to a nav menu, you're saving the ID itself to the menu, and WP dynamically calculates the correct permalink for that ID every time the menu is pulled up. (It also dynamically pulls the post Title unless you have overridden it in the menu settings.) Since you could have the same ID in every subsite, if you just save a post ID into the nav menu, there's no way to tell WordPress, "Look for this ID on this other subsite." WordPress is always going to just look for that ID in the current site's post table.

However, you can switch blog IDs in PHP theme templates, so you may be able to find a different way to build your menu - one that doesn't use native WP nav menus. The `switch_to_blog()` function switches to pull information from a specific (numbered by ID) subsite, so you could pull links from one site, then links from a second site (and so on if you have more sites) and display them all together in a header, for example.

Comment: So, your are suggesting that I call `switch_to_blog()` followed by calling  `wp_update_nav_menu_item()` and then `restore_current_blog()`, right? What I did is call `switch_to_blog()`, retrieve the page ID, then call `restore_current_blog()' then `wp_update_nav_menu_item()` right at the end. Maybe this is what caused things to go off. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think this would work. I will try it, but I have my suspicion. If I switch to another blog, then the menu item will be created for that other blog! Maybe I should change my approach altogether.

Comment: No - I am saying you cannot use WP Nav Menus the way you want to, because unless you write a very unusual nav walker, WP will always look in the site it's currently on for all the page IDs in the menu. So it will only link to content on the current site. I am saying, build out the PHP logic to grab pages and switch blog IDs in a template that does not use nav menus at all.